# Build error for FABS, Xcode uses different header file (math.h vs tgmath.h)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, math.h

I have a method which uses FABS

```
return  (fabs(x - y) <= EPSILON);
```

It compiles and builds fine on four of my machines, but when I recently tried to configure another new machine i get a weird build error whereby it says
"ApplicationBackgroundColor.m:146:14: Called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer"

On closer inspection it seems that the FABS is pointing [when i command click it in Xcode] to *tgmath.h*; while for the other machines that is working it is supposed to be redirected to *math.h* in **/usr/include** of the iOS simulator.

The entire repository is directly cloned from git and there are no difference between those working and those not working - the code and the project workspaces. Therefore, as far as I can tell, there must be something else I'm missing.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it:

Open terminal

type -->  xcode-select --install

It could be related to not find the math.h where it is defined

It is for installing the command-line tool again. Many times it solves this kind of problems. And after doing it restart XCode